# Stop "navigate to" after performing HTTP.put request

Tags: javascript, http, async-await, put

[image]I am having an issue where I make an HTTP put request to a local JSON server using async, await, this works fine, it's just when the put request is completed the page is essentially refreshing which I don't want and I can seem to stop it. I have tried using e.preventDefault() but it doesn't seem to work. I have a basic HTML page, and most of the elements in my HTML page are being served up dynamically using javascript. I target the save-connection button which calls my http.put request, this works fine, then I serve up the previous data with getAllConnections() and ui.showConnections(connectionsAvailable), this flashes up for a second, then immediately the put request sends a response and I get the navigated to localhost:5500/index.html?#. How can I stop the navigate to from happening?

My http library is in a separate js file:

http.js

```
     async put(url, data) {

       const response = await fetch(url, {
               method: 'PUT',
               headers: {
                   'Content-type': 'application/json'
               },
               body: JSON.stringify(data)
           });
           const resdData = await response.json();
           return resdData;
    }
```

app.js

```
//Save connection changes
function saveConnection() {

   // Update connection with PUT
    http.put(`http://localhost:3000/connections/${selectedConnection.id}`, selectedConnection)
        .then(data => {
            getAllConnections()
            ui.showConnections(connectionsAvailable)})

        .catch(err => console.log(err))  
}


    //function to display check info entered in edit connection
    editConnection.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        function hasClass(elem, className) {
            return elem.className.split(' ').indexOf(className) > -1;
        }
        //check connection name is characters between 2 and 25 long
        if (hasClass(e.target, 'data')) {
            console.log(data)
            validateName()
            e.preventDefault()
        } else if (hasClass(e.target, 'cancel')) {
            getAllConnections()
            ui.showConnections(connectionsAvailable)

            e.preventDefault()
        } 
        //overwrite tank information
        else if (hasClass(e.target,`save-connection`)){
            let connectionNewName = document.querySelector('.connection-name').value;
            let connectionNewIpAddress = document.querySelector('.ipAddress').value;
            let connectionNewPort = document.querySelector('.port').value;

            assignselectedConnection(selectedConnection.id, connectionNewName, connectionNewIpAddress, connectionNewPort)

            saveConnection()

            e.preventDefault()
        }
```

the data being served/save-connection button that I target

```
editConnection(connectionName, connectionIpAddress, connectionPort) {
      const params = document.getElementById('data');
      const connectionData = `
      <div class="container">
      <div class="card mb-3 mt-3">
        <div class="card">
          <h5 class="card-header text-left">
            Enter Connection Data:
          </h5>
          <div class="card-body">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group text-left">
                <label for="connection-name">Please enter a Connection Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="connection-name form-control " id="connection-name" placeholder="${connectionName}">
                <div class="invalid-feedback"> Name must be between 2 and 25 characters
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group text-left">
                <label for="ipAddress">Please enter an IP Address:</label>
                <input type="text" class="ipAddress form-control" id="ipAddress" placeholder="${connectionIpAddress}">
                <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please enter a valid IP Address in the format 192.168.200.100
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group text-left">
                <label for="port">Please enter a Port:</label>
                <input type="number" class="port form-control" id="port" placeholder="${connectionPort}">
                <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please enter a valid 4 figure port number eg 8080
                </div>
              </div>

            <div class="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="col">
                    <button href="#" [![enter image description here][1]][1]type="button" class="save-connection btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block">Save Connection</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <button href="#" type="button" class="cancel btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block">Cancel</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Hi have updated the code, and changed the button to be of type "button" not submit. I did have it set to button originally, but changed it to submit to see if it prevented the behaviour. The problem is still happening. I will include an image to show the naviage t to that I am trying to prevent

Answer (score 0):

Your button is a `submit` button. The behaviour of a submit button is to submit the form - which is exactly what is happening.

Just change your button to a normal button. There is no need for it to be a submit.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, but I am still getting the same issue. I have included an image and underlined in red the behaviour I am trying to prevent. I was originally using type="button" but and change to type="submit" to see if it stopped the page refreshing. Is there anything else that I can try. You will see in the image "Tanks 1 192.168.100.100 1222" printed in the console is the original data I then overwrite this with the post method and replace all with empty characters and then get the navigated to 127.0.0.1:5500  behaviour that I am trying to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting a form element.

If you want to keep using the `click` event, remove the `<form>` tag, and make your button `type="button"`.

If you want to keep using the  tag, you must listen to the `submit` event on the form, and use `ev.preventDefault()` on that event.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, but I am still getting the same issue. I have included an image and underlined in red the behaviour I am trying to prevent. I was originally using type="button" but and change to type="submit" to see if it stopped the page refreshing. Is there anything else that I can try. You will see in the image "Tanks 1 192.168.100.100 1222" printed in the console is the original data I then overwrite this with the post method and replace all with empty characters and then get the navigated to 127.0.0.1:5500  behaviour that I am trying to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `return false` at the end of `click` handler:

```
   editConnection.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

       ....

       return false;

   }
```